# How to implement a process that differs from thread in java?

Tags: java, process

I know that threads and processes are related, and that threads are a small unit
of process. But I doubt that, how to implement a process using simple java code?

Please show me some code for doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: `java YourClass` will create single process which will run in one or more threads (depending on code in `YourClass`). If you want to create separate process within your Java code then you should take a look at ProcessBuilder class.

Comment: This may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237701/do-threads-created-in-java-behave-differently-on-windows-and-linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot implement a process using Java. Each Java program
runs within a single OS process; this OS process is the JVM.
If you want another process, start another (or the same) Java
program in another JVM instance.

Comment: Actually, the “one JVM”==“one process” is an implementation-specific detail. There is no defined relationship between JVMs and processes.

Comment: @Holger Good to know that. Thanks. It's quite a "detail" though.

Comment: It becomes interesting when you implement a “distributed JVM” where each Java thread might run on a different computer. The specification leaves enough room to allow that. However, your answer still holds, there is no standard API to create a process inside the JVM, a process remains a concept outside the scope of a JVM.

Comment: @Holger Really good to know. Honestly, I have never thought about a distributed JVM.